# Selecting inside range over go channel

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm following [this post](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) to parallelise my app. I need to tailor this code:

```
func sq(done <-chan struct{}, in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for n := range in {
            select {
            case out <- n * n:
            case <-done:
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    return out
}
```

I don't fully understand the line `case out <- n * n:`. I can see it's saying that if there's a value for `n`, then square it and send it down the channel, but I don't understand why. Does `select` just take the first `true` case? Could it be rewritten:

```
for n := range in {
    select {
    case n:
       out <- n * n
    case <-done:
       return
    }
}
```

Anyway, I need to replace the line `case out <- n * n:` with a function call. I've changed it to the following:

```
out := make(chan structs.Ticket)

go func() {
    defer close(out)
    for url := range inputChannel {
        select {
        case url:
            data, err := GetData(url)
            fmt.Println("Got error: ", err)
            out <- data
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}()

return out
```

It looks like this will compile (I can't compile it yet), but because it's not simple to debug parallel code I wanted to check that using `case url` was the right way to select on a channel in a `range`. Is this right?

**Update**

OK I've removed the remaining issues with my code, and now when I try to compile I get the error messages:

```
url evaluated but not used
select case must be receive, send or assign recv
```

Comment: I think you're confusing `select` and `switch` statements. The `select` cases are only concerned with channel operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Being in a `range` or not doesn't have any impact on what `select` is doing here.
2. No, `select` doesn't take the first true expression... it doesn't take expressions at all. The only things that can appear as the cases of an expression are channel sends, channel receives, and assignments with channel receives on their right side.

   ```
   select {
   case out <- n * n:
   case <-done:
       return
   }
   ```

says "if sending on `out` is possible (i.e. it has remaining capacity or an active reader), then send the value `n * n` to it and continue. If receiving from `done` is possible, return from the function. If both are possible, choose one at random and do it. If neither is possible, wait until one of them becomes possible." (See [Select Statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) in the spec).

If the value you want to send needs to be computed (and it's too complex to put on the right hand side of the channel send), simply do it before the `select`. The spec makes it clear that all of the expressions in send statements in a select are computed ahead of time anyway, so nothing is lost.

Comment: You say to compute the value before the select, but my `GetData` function takes a few minutes to complete. If there's something on `done` I want to return immediately. Calling `GetData` after the `range` will run that expensive function even if `done` is ready to read. Is there an alternative that will only run `GetData` if `out` can accept the write?

Comment: Great! I could not understand why the **case <-done** clause would ever execute if there was a value in **n**. However I missed the fact that the first case statement is actually testing the *sending* to the **out** channel and not the reading from the in channel.

Answer (score 0):

> *I don't fully understand the line `case out <- n * n`:. I can see it's saying that if there's a value for n, then square it and send it down the channel, but I don't understand why.*

That's not correct. `case out <- n * n` checks to see if `out` is ready to read, and sends `n * n` to `out` if it is. Unless `done` is also ready.

`select` is used when you have multiple channels to talk to. Whichever channel is ready, it will do that case. If multiple channels are ready, it will select one at random.

```
select {
    case out <- n * n:
    case <-done:
        return
    }
}
```

This will select over `out` and `done`. If either is ready to proceed, ie. `out` is ready to read or there's something to read from `done`, it will pick one of those cases. The order is random, so it is possible to send more down `out` even if there's something to be read from `done`.

This pattern is used to shut down infinite goroutines. If you stop reading from its output channel, it won't do any more work, but it will hang around in memory. So by passing a value to `done` you can tell the goroutine to shut down.

---

***UPDATE***: In your original case, where the goroutine is looping over an input channel and sending output, `done` is an unnecessary complication. Once the input channel is closed, the function will return.

```
func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for n := range in {
            out <- n * n
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    in := make(chan int)
    out := sq(in)
    for _,i := range []int{1,2,3,4} {
        in <- i
        fmt.Println(<-out)
    }

    // The `range` inside the goroutine from sq() will exit,
    // and the goroutine will return.
    close(in)
}
```

If it just spat out an ever increasing set of squares, then `done` would be necessary inside an infinite loop.

```
func sq(done chan bool) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        n := 0
        for {
            select {
                case <-done:
                    return
                case out<-n*n:
                    n++
            }
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    out := sq(done)
    for range []int{1,2,3,4} {
        fmt.Println(<-out)
    }

    // The switch in the goroutine will be able to read
    // from done (out's buffer being already full) and return.
    done <- true
}
```

Comment: I'm applying this pattern to a more complex pipeline. If you read the linked blog post you'll see they use the `done` channel to cancel the entire pipeline on error. I'm not actually computing squares.

Comment: @jbrown If it's just looping over an input channel, regardless of what its doing inside there, you can just as easily close the goroutine on error by closing the input channel.

Comment: It's part of a fan-out/fan-in pipeline so not that straightforward according to the post. But it's the first time I've implemented that in go so it might be simpler.

Comment: @jbrown I believe they use `done` there to shut down *multiple* goroutines at the same time regardless of their input channel. If you don't need that sort of coordination, closing the input channel works fine. If you do, then yes something like that is the way to go.